# Show that there is an uncountable number of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers equivalent to any given Cauchy sequence of rational number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Please check my proof :)]

We must show if given $\epsilon >0$ we can find n>N such that $|S_{n}-L_{n}|<\epsilon $

We set up $|S_n-L_n|$ for any uncountable cauch sequence as

$$|S_{1}-L_{1}|<\frac{\epsilon }{2}$$

and for any cauchy sequence of rational number as

$$|S_{2}-L_{2}|< \frac{\epsilon }{2}$$

then

$$|S_{n}-L_{n}| = |S_{1}-L_{1}+S_{2}-L_{2}|\leq |S_{1}-L_{1}|+|S_{2}-L_{2}|\leq \frac{\epsilon }{2}+\frac{\epsilon }{2}=\epsilon $$

Comment: Uncountable Cauchy sequence? There are no uncountable sequences. And where do you get $\epsilon = |S_1-L_1+S_2-L_2|$ from?

Comment: Um this problem is from the way of analysis  by Robert I copied it without edit any word or the question is wrong?

Comment: Let me rephrase, no sequence is uncountable. There are only countably many terms in any sequence. The question is to prove that for each Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$ the set $\{(b_n)\mid (b_n) \ \text{equivalent to}\ (a_n)\}$ is uncountable. You only have _one_ $(L_n)$.

Comment: @Ennar ok thank ^ ^

Comment: $|S_n-L_n| = |S_1-L_1+S_2-L_2|$ is still wrong. Please rethink what you need to show again.

Comment: @Ennar thank for comment ^ ^. I just tried to mimic the proof from similiar question in the book

Comment: Ask yourself whether you reached conclusion: "There are _uncountably_ many sequences equivalent to my original Cauchy sequence." If you look at your work, there is nothing even remotely closed to that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let's say that you have convergent sequence $(a_n)$. Could you find uncountably many sequences $(b_n)$ such that $\lim_na_n=\lim_nb_n$? To further hint toward solution, what do you know about subsequences of convergent sequence and how many of them are there?

Cauchy sequences of rational numbers converge to real numbers, so if you can answer the above question, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

For any real $r \in (0,1)$
take its binary representation
$r = \sum b_k/2^k$
and add $b_k/2^k$
to the k-th element of the sequence.
This will converge to the same value.

Since there are and uncountable number of reals,
this gives an uncountable number of sequences that converge to the same value.