# On the proof of "Show that there is an uncountable number of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers equivalent to any given Cauchy..."

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

**Show that there is an uncountable number of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers equivalent to any given Cauchy sequence of rational numbers.**

*Proof.*

**UPDATE:** previous choice of $x_k^\prime$ did not work as it is suggested also by the answer below, so I'm trying with a different $x_k^\prime$.

Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,$ be a given Cauchy sequence of rationals with limit $r$, and consider the set of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers $A = \{(x_1^{(1)},x_2^{(1)},\ldots), (x_{1}^{(2)},x_{2}^{(2)},\ldots),\ldots\}$, which are all equivalent to $x_1,x_2,\ldots$, i.e. for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $m_i$ (depending on $x_1^{(i)},x_2^{(i)},x_3^{(i)}$), such that $|x_j^{(i)}-x_j|<1/n$ for all $j>m_i$. We show that the set $A$ is uncountable. Assume for the sake of a contradiction that $A$ is countable. Then, there is a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$ which maps elements of $\mathbb{N}$ with elements of $A$. That is, we can list the elements of $A$ as follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(1) &= &x_{1}^{(1)},x_{2}^{(1)},x_{3}^{(1)},x_{4}^{(1)},x_{5}^{(1)},\ldots\\
f(2)& = &x_{1}^{(2)},x_{2}^{(2)},x_{3}^{(2)},x_{4}^{(2)},x_{5}^{(2)},\ldots\\
f(3)& = &x_{1}^{(3)},x_{2}^{(3)},x_{3}^{(3)},x_{4}^{(3)},x_{5}^{(3)},\ldots\\
f(4)& = &x_{1}^{(4)},x_{2}^{(4)},x_{3}^{(4)},x_{4}^{(4)},x_{5}^{(4)},\ldots\\
f(5)& = &x_{1}^{(5)},x_{2}^{(5)},x_{3}^{(5)},x_{4}^{(5)},x_{5}^{(5)},\ldots\\
\vdots &=& \vdots\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Consider the following sequence of rationals $x_{1}^\prime,x_2^\prime,\ldots$, with
$$
x_k^\prime = 
\begin{cases} 
x_k^{(k)}/2 & \text{ if } x_k^{(k)} \neq 0\\
1/k & \text{ if } x_k^{(k)} = 0.
\end{cases}
$$ We see that $x_k^\prime\not\in A$. To complete the proof we show that $x_k^\prime$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals and that it is equivalent to $x_k$.

For note that 
$$
|x_{j}^\prime - x_k^\prime| =
\begin{cases} 
|x_{j}^{(j)}/2-x_k^{(k)}/2| \text{ if } x_j^{(j)}\neq 0,x_k^{(k)}\neq 0\\
|x_{j}^{(j)}/2-1/k| \text{ if } x_j^{(j)}\neq 0,x_k^{(k)}= 0\\
|1/j-x_k^{(k)}/2| \text{ if } x_j^{(j)}= 0,x_k^{(k)}\neq 0\\
|1/j-1/k| \text{ if } x_j^{(j)}= 0,x_k^{(k)}=0.
\end{cases}
$$

Now, for a given error 1/n, we need to find an $m$, s.t. $|x_{j}^{(j)}-x_k^{(k)}|\leq 1/n$ for all $j,k\geq m$. But I can't figure out how to do it since changing the index implies changing the sequence as well. Any suggestion?

Is it meaningful to proceed this way or would you go by producing a specific set of equivalent Cauchy sequences or rationals?

Comment: Hint: $|1/j-1/k|\le|1/j|+|1/k|\le 2/m$.Then make $m$ bigger if you need to.

Comment: I was writing the answer based on my hint, and then I realised that there may be bigger problems with your proof. Please see below.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your proof has bigger problems than the fact that you cannot get rid of $\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{k}$. Look at the following Cauchy sequences - all equivalent to $0,0,0,0,0,\ldots$:

$$\begin{matrix}0,&0,&0,&0,&0,&\ldots\\0,&\frac{1}{2},&0,&0,&0,&\ldots\\0,&0,&\frac{2}{3},&0,&0,&\ldots\\0,&0,&0,&\frac{3}{4},&0,&\ldots\\0,&0,&0,&0,&\frac{4}{5},&\ldots\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\end{matrix}$$

Wouldn't your construction end up producing the sequence $1,1,1,1,\ldots$, which is not equivalent to either the starting sequence $0,0,0,0,\ldots$ nor to any of those other sequences?

---

To prove the original statement, I would use a different construction. Let $(x_n)_{ n\in\mathbb N}$ be a rational Cauchy sequence. For every subset $X\subset\mathbb N$ we can construct another sequence:

$$y^{(X)}_n=x_n+\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}_X(n)=x_n+\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n}&n\in X\\0&n\not\in X\end{cases}$$

where $\mathbf{1}_X$ is the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the subset $X$.

It can be proven that:

- Each of those sequences $(y^{(X)}_n)$ is a rational Cauchy sequence,
- Each of those sequences is equivalent to $(x_n)$, and
- All of those sequences are different (for different subsets $X$).

Thus there are at least as many rational Cauchy sequences equivalent to to a given one as there are subsets of $\mathbb N$. With a well-known theorem (which itself uses Cantor's diagonal argument in the proof!) that there are uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb N$, we reach the intended conclusion.

---

Having said all this, I wonder if the OP's argument can be fixed - to still produce a new sequence, out of countably many Cauchy sequences equivalent to the original sequence, which will itself be equivalent to the original sequence, using some sort of Cantor's diagonal argument. (Maybe someone would come up with another answer on those lines?)

Comment: my sequence follows somehow Cantor's diagonalisation idea...anyway, those you produced are only a subset of all the equivalent Cauchy sequences of 0.

Comment: @utobi And so is yours ;) (The whole point is that you cannot list them *all* in one sequence of sequences...)

Comment: sure, we try to list them in order to get a contradiction. The point is that my sequence is generic, your's follows a specific pattern, and that's misleading because the sequence is infinite, and there are many other possible patterns that you have not considered.

Comment: It takes only one counterexample to refute it... I suggest you try to follow your proof, but imagine that my sequences are the ones you chose initially - and then figure out where it breaks. I *think* it is in the assumption that there is such $m_j, m_k$: in the beginning you said (rightfully) that $m_i$ depended on $i$, so I am curious how you can conclude that *one* $m_j$ suffices across the whole diagonal.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point. I mean, here I'm assuming $A$ is countable and each of its elements is a Cauchy sequence equivalent to $x_k$. Are you saying that this assumption is false? As about $x_k^\prime$, see the answer by Paramanand Singh here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098613/show-that-there-is-an-uncountable-number-of-cauchy-sequences-of-rational-numbers?rq=1. Anyway, thank you for your effort!

Comment: I am familiar enough with Cantor's diagonal argument, but it just doesn't work in your case. "Are you saying that this assumption is false" - no, I am fine with you assuming that there are countably many Cauchy sequences equivalent to the initial sequence, and trying to construct a *new* Cauchy sequence different from all the previous ones, but still equivalent to the initial one. What I am saying is that you won't be able to prove that this newly-constructed sequence is equivalent to the initial one - and my example shows you that. The answer you linked to is also wrong, as far as I can see.

Comment: (Cont'd) This is not to say that a *different *construction won't do the job - it is just this construction (in your question, and in the linked answer) doesn't work. I would myself probably construct the whole uncountable lot of equivalent sequences at once, by assigning every subset $X\subset\mathbb N$ to a sequence $y_n=x_n+\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2^n}&n\in X\\0&n\not\in X\end{cases}$...

Comment: I updated my question by using a different counter example, somehow similar to yours...but yet the proof of Cauchyness seem not straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Two Cauchy sequences $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ and $(b_n)_{n\geq0}$ of rational numbers are called *equivalent* if $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n-b_n|=0$. In this case the two sequences converge to the same real number $\xi\in{\mathbb R}$.

Assume that $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers, and let $n\to\sigma_n\in\{-1,1\}$ $\>(n\geq0)$ be an arbitrary sign sequence. Then $$r_n=a_n+  \sigma_n \>2^{-n}\qquad(n\geq0)$$
defines a sequence $n\mapsto r_n$ $(n\geq0)$ of rational numbers which is equivalent to $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$. Furthermore different sign sequences $(\sigma_n)_{n\geq0}$ lead to different sequences $(r_n)_{n\geq0}$. Since there are uncountably many such sign sequences we obtain uncountably many different rational sequences $(r_n)_{n\geq0}$ equivalent to $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$.

Comment: neet! but suppose I don't have the notion of limit yet. What about proving that $r_n$ is equivalent to $a_n$ without using the notion of limit?

Comment: I have just replaced your ${1\over n}$ by $2^{-n}$.